# rgl: How to use more than 8 colors when coloring based on tSNE cluster

Tags: r, rgl, seurat

Running the following code I get 15 clusters with tSNE, but when I go to color by cluster (that is, identity), I only get a maximum of 8 colors.

```
library(Seurat)
library(rgl)

example <- RunTSNE(example, dims.use = PC, do.fast = TRUE, dim.embed = 3)

example_1 <- example@dr$tsne@cell.embeddings[,1]
example_2 <- example@dr$tsne@cell.embeddings[,2]
example_3 <- example@dr$tsne@cell.embeddings[,3]

plot3d(x = example_1, y = example_2, z = example_3, col = 
as.numeric(example@ident))
```

This is a problem because the 3D tSNE plot that is created has differing clusters with the same color.

Is there a different way of using more colors (15) so that every cluster has its own color?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `col = rainbow(15)[as.numeric(example@ident)]`

Comment: This worked like a charm, G5W. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use the `palette()` function (from the base `grDevices` package) to set your palette to `rainbow(15)` (or any other list of colors) and then your original code will work.

Answer (score 1):

This expands on the comments from G5W and myself.

`rgl` uses the standard base graphics system for specifying colours.  You can give them by name, RGB encoding, or number in a palette.  See the `?col2rgb` help page for more details on this system.

If you want to use 15 separate numeric values, you probably need to set a larger palette than the default one.  The `?rainbow` help page describes several functions for generating colours; there is also the `RColorBrewer` package that defines nicer palettes, but none with as many as 15 colours.

Using `rainbow(15)` will get 15 different colours.  Just add

```
palette(rainbow(15))
```

before the `plot3d` call, and you'll automatically get them.  You can then add a legend using

```
legend3d("right", legend = levels(example@ident), fill = palette())
```

The legend is a bitmap, so if you intend to save the image for printing, expand the window to the full size before adding the legend.